# Hyperdesktop alternative for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: screen, cloud, shutter

I recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04.

I found most software that I used on Windows for Ubuntu. Which is why I'm here.. There's an application for Windows called "Hyperdesktop". With this application you can take a picture of a selected area or the whole screen and it'll automatically upload to imgur.com and replace your clipboard w/ the URL of the image you've just snapped.

I use this application on a daily basis on Windows and I was wondering is there any good alternatives? I tried *shutter* and *screencloud* and both do something similar to what I'd want but it's not the same. It doesn't necessarily have to upload to imgur either, any image hosting site or even FTP would be fine. Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to add that you can use hotkeys. For example you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> at the same time and you can choose a selected area.

Answer (score 0):

The default screenshot application in Ubuntu enables you to do just that. Just open the dash and search for "screenshot" and you'll find it. Now, if you get yourself an Ubuntu One account, then you can just save to that, and it'll be uploaded automatically.

Comment: Thank you Jo-Erlend but that's not what I'm looking for unless I'm doing something wrong. I don't see anywhere where I can use hot keys, which is rather important for me. Also it did upload to my Ubuntu One but I'd prefer it upload to an image sharing site for instant sharing. Once again, thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Good luck on your hunt. And if you find what you're looking for, remember to post it here? :)